# md-datepicker must be a Date instance Error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, angular-material

I have a problem here. I want to use Angular Material datepicker in my modal form. I simply added it to my form like this

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="new.warranty" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
```

And if I submitting form I got this:

```
Sun Apr 03 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (EEST)
```

But I want to convert data in yyyy-MM-dd format before send, so I tried to convert date format in this way

```
data.warranty = $filter('date')(Date.parse(data.warranty), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

So my form rly send a required yyyy-MM-dd format, but I get an error every time, when I sumbitting form.

```
`The ng-model for md-datepicker must be a Date instance. Currently the model is a: string`
```

so, how can I prevent this error, without using moment.js, if it possible, please.

Comment: Isn't it better to keep your model as a `Date`, and then parsing it wherever you want to actually display it?

Comment: Actually, I am just learning, so I have no idea what you speaking about. Can you show an example? And I don`t need to display it, I should send it to server, and a server expecting for a yyyy-MM-dd format

Comment: I'm speculating here, but you can try setting `ng-model` to the old date that returned `Sun Apr 03 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0300 (EEST)` (to keep the date picker working), and then add a `ng-value` attribute with a parsed in `yyyy-MM-dd` value of that `Date`.

Comment: That's all good in theory, by doesn't work for me in practice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use `$filter('date')` on your `data.warranty`, you transform it from a `Date` object to a `String`, hence the error.

#### Option 1

The fastest way to solve this is to have a duplicate of your date value as a string:

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="new.warrantyDate" md-placeholder="Enter date"></md-datepicker>
```

Whenever you submit the form, before making a request, transform the date in the format you need, **but don't overwrite the existing date**:

```
data.warranty = $filter('date')(Date.parse(data.warrantyDate), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Thus your `warrantyDate` value will remain a `Date` object and will continue working. In case you modify the date in your response, do not forget to synchronize the `warrantyDate` with the modified date.

#### Option 2

Another option you could try is create a directive that will have different `$modelValue` and `$viewValue` for your `data.warranty` variable. For more information on how you can achieve this, consult the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController) on `ngModelController`.

The second option requires a deeper understanding of how angular works, so if you're at the very beginning of your angularjs path, you might go well with the first option.

Comment: I cant use the first solution because I should use `ng-model` to show `warranty` that already exists in DB. I have a lot of places in my code, where I should use `date` format transformation, so I will try to use the second one. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

i've solved this issue by overriding md-datepicke
,Here is code

```
 .directive('mdDatepicker', function ($parse) {

    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function (scope, elem, attr, ngModel) {
            $parse(attr.ngModel).assign(scope, new Date(_.get(scope, attr.ngModel)));
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: hey Wael, when I try your directive, it shows the datepicker with Invalid Date on load.  Do you get this as well?

Comment: hi,please add jsfiddle